# How to check if a url path exists in the service worker cache

Tags: caching, service-worker

I need to check if a particular URL path exists in the service worker cache.
For example, suppose my URL is:

/myserviceworker/service?a=110&b=70

this URL exists in the cache, but there are many of them with different values of a and b.

Now, suppose I want to refresh all of these URLs, how can I do that?

I want to know how to access the key values from Service Worker cache.

If I know the key, my plan is as follows:

```
var url = new URL(key);

if(url.pathname === "\/myserviceworker/service")

then refetch the key
```

But I am not sure how to get the cache key and in what format it is. I mean, is it a string or is it already a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache API has a [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match) method which returns a promise resolving in a Response object if match or `undefined` if no match exists. The second parameter is an object where you can specify `ignoreSearch` to not take into account URL parameters.

The `ignoreSearch` option is actually [supported only by Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1143833) ([Chrome status here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=520784)).

In the other hand, to retrieve all the cache entries, you can use the [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/keys) method.